# Mysql usage "AS"

Tags: mysql

I am a web developer, I have faced on this problem...
I am developing statistic web app part using php and mysql.

```
SELECT
  IF (cat1 = "S4", 1, 0) AS ncat1,
  IF (cat2 = "S4", 1, 0) AS ncat2,
  IF (cat3 = "S4", 1, 0) AS ncat3,
  IF (cat4 = "S4", 1, 0) AS ncat4,
  (ncat1 + ncat2 + ncat3 + ncat4) AS ntotal
FROM
  users
```

I want to get ntotal like this format. but it does not work, unknown column ncat1
so, I think  fullstack developers can help me easier and quickly
Help me please....
Thank you...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. *does not work* is, with respect, not enough information to help you, or us, figure out what is going wrong. Error messages are your friends!

Comment: ncat1 - ncat4 are not available in your calculation of ntotal , you can repeat all the ifs

Comment: How can I repeats?

Comment: can you share table structure?

Comment: .....cate1 cate2 cate3 cate4 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *aliases* (i.e. `ncat1`) are not available to be used in your SQL statement.

I'd use a simple subquery to resolve this:

```
SELECT  ncat1, ncat2, ncat3, ncat4,
        (ncat1 + ncat2 + ncat3 + ncat4) AS ntotal
  FROM  (
        SELECT
          IF (cat1 = "S4", 1, 0) AS ncat1,
          IF (cat2 = "S4", 1, 0) AS ncat2,
          IF (cat3 = "S4", 1, 0) AS ncat3,
          IF (cat4 = "S4", 1, 0) AS ncat4
        FROM
          users
        ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ncat1` and other column names aren't in scope for your `(ncat1 + ncat2 + ncat3 + ncat4) AS ntotal` line. So you can't refer to them there.

Try using a subquery to bring them into scope, something like this:

```
SELECT *, (ncat1 + ncat2 + ncat3 + ncat4) AS ntotal
  FROM (
      SELECT
         IF (cat1 = "S4", 1, 0) AS ncat1,
         IF (cat2 = "S4", 1, 0) AS ncat2,
         IF (cat3 = "S4", 1, 0) AS ncat3,
         IF (cat4 = "S4", 1, 0) AS ncat4
     FROM coursered
      ) subquery
```